# SAS: Using Do/Loop in a Proc Transpose

Tags: sas, transpose

I'm  not very familiar with Do Loops in SAS and was hoping to get some help.  I have data that looks like this:

Product A: 1

Product A: 2

Product A: 4

I'd like to transpose (easy) and flag that Product A: 3 is missing, but I need to do this iteratively to the i-th degree since the number of products is large.

If I run the transpose part in SAS, my first column will be 1, second column will be 2, and third column will be 4 - but I'd really like the third column to be missing and the fourth column to be 4.

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: This is the missing levels issue, what do you want your output to be and what have you tried?

Comment: Ideally, I wanted my output to look like:

product A: 1 2 . 4

But when I transpose, my data looks like:
Product A: 1 2 4

I'm proc summarizing now and that works okay, but it is not scalable when I have to replicate this every month.

Comment: Is it actually numeric? How can you identify 3 as missing?

Comment: Essentially you need some source that has all the options and you merge them via a full or cross join so you have all records.

Answer (score 0):

Get some sample data:

```
proc sort data=sashelp.iris out=sorted;
  by species;
run;
```

Determine the largest column we will need to transpose to.  Depending on your situation you may just want to hardcode this value using a `%let max=somevalue;` statement:

```
proc sql noprint;  
  select cats(max(sepallength)) into :max from sorted;
quit;

%put &=max;
```

Transpose the data using a data step:

```
data want;
  set sorted;
  by species; 
  retain _1-_&max;

  array a[1:&max] _1-_&max;

  if first.species then do;
    do cnt = lbound(a) to hbound(a);
      a[cnt] = .;
    end;
  end;

  a[sepallength] = sepallength;

  if last.species then do;
    output;
  end;

  keep species _1-_&max;
run;
```

Notice we are defining an array of columns: `_1,_2,_3,..._max`.  This happens in our `array` statement.

We then use by-group processing to populate these newly created columns for a single species at a time.  For each species, on the first record, we clear the array.  For each record of the species, we populate the appropriate element of the array.  On the final record for the species output the array contents.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to tell SAS that you have 4 products and the values are 1-4.  In this example I create dummy ID with the needed information then transpose using ID statement to name new variables using the value of product.

```
data product;
   input id product @@;
   cards;
1 1 1 2 1 4
2 2 2 3
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data productspace;
   if 0 then set product;
   do product = 1 to 4;
      output;
      end;
   stop; 
   run;
data productV / view=productV;
   set productspace product;
   run;
proc transpose data=productV out=wide(where=(not missing(id))) prefix=P;
   by id;
   var product;
   id product;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]